# install odoo14 on ubuntu 20 on AWS lightsail This site can’t be reached44.202.124.139 refused to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, odoo

server from AWS lightsail
pinging reply

[image]

service is running

[image]

[image]

However I got this error

This site can’t be reached
44.202.124.139 refused to connect.
[image]

and port is allowed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your security groups if it allows port 8069 (and other ports you are using) by the inbound rules. Also, check if your Ubuntu's firewall is enabled. If it is then also configure it to allow those port(s). This should make it possible to connect to your server from the outside to the specific port.

If the problem still persists then I would think that it is not port-related and will try to look at other places for more clues.

Comment: thank you so much
the port is allowed already